# Starters for 1500 litre brewing with 100 g of Dry Yeast

Tags: yeast, brewing, starter, pitching

What is the possible way to brew batch like 1500 liter with 100 g of yeast ?
And how many starter steps need to go and how long will it take to get target pitch rate ? 
Thanks all !!

P.S I'm new member !!

Comment: Just to confirm you want to brew 375 gallons (about 10 bbl system) starting with 100 grams of yeast?

Comment: Yes sir and i need to propagate using 100 grams of dry yeast to the amount that need to pitch for 1500 liter.

Answer (score 2):

You need about 13,500 billion cells for 375 gallons of 1.050 wort.

Thats about 750 grams of dry yeast.

To propagate 100g to your pitch rate you can do a single 50 gallon starter. Which will cause a 3-4 fold growth resulting in trub with cell equivalents to 800-1600 grams of dry yeast.

Comment: Sir do u mean i need only one starter to get 800-1600 grams of dry yeast ?

Comment: @ThantHtooAung yea, with 50 gallons wort and pitching 100 grams, when done it will have doubled about 3 times, giving the equivilant cells that 800grams of dry yeast has. Depending how the starter is done to promote growth of could double again (4 times). But 3 times is with minimal effort.

Comment: According to data from Brewer friend's pitch rate calculator,it shows that i ll get 4200 billion cells with 200 liter of wort as single starter but how can i know the grams of dry yeast inside container ? I m confused with that !!

Comment: @ThantHtooAung you should contact your yeast provider ask them the best way to propagate thier yeast. You have to realize at these volumes your not using a stirplate. Your using a yeast incubator, basically a nano brewery fermentor with constant forced O2. In the end for your pitch you want about 20 liters of slurry, which you will from 200 liter starter.

Comment: @ThantHtooAung You could use a cell count plate with a microscope to approximate the population empirically instead of using prediction models.

Comment: So if i got 1 billion cells per ml after cell count and what is the total cell count for container containing 2 liter of wort and unknown amount of yeast slurry? Or Do i need to take yeast slurry only to get total cell count in that yeast slurry??

Comment: @ThantHtooAung whatever the solution it should be well mixed when drawing your sample for your cell count. That's the only way to know the count on the entire volume.

Comment: Ok sir !! Tysm for your time and information !!

Answer (score 0):

Scaling conservatively (1:10) you would need 1.5L, 15L, and 150L stages. Actual growth rate will be determined by how well you can keep the solution aerated. Are you producing biofuel?

Comment: No sir. I m just junior fermentation scientist in craft brewery. So my boss wants me to propagate to the amount they want for 1500 liter brewing which is around 14000 billion cells. But unfortunately,i dont have enough container to do a starter for scale that u told sir !!